# Query the list of names from table which have vowels (i.e., a, e, i, o, and u) as both their first and last characters

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I want to query the list of CITY names from the table STATION(id, city, longitude, latitude) which have vowels as both their first and last characters. The result cannot contain duplicates.

For this is I wrote a query like WHERE NAME LIKE 'a%' that had 25 conditions, each vowel for every other vowel, which is quite unwieldy. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Hint:  `regexp_like(name, '^[aeiouAEIOU].*[aeiouAEIOU]$')`

Comment: Add some sample data and sqlfiddle and post back a link.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `regexp_like` with case insesitive match parameter `'i'` to perform case insesitive search as following:

```
Select distinct city 
  from station
 Where regexp_like(city, '^[aeiou].*[aeiou]$','i');
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

You've probably seen Gordon's comment and suggestion to use regular expressions.

Another option might be to use `substr` + `IN`, such as

```
SQL> with test (city) as
  2    (select 'London'     from dual union all
  3     select 'Alondoni'   from dual union all
  4     select 'eroma'      from dual union all
  5     select 'Bar celona' from dual union all
  6     select 'Iud apesta' from dual
  7    )
  8  select city
  9  from test
 10  where lower(substr(city, 1, 1)) in ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')
 11    and lower(substr(city, -1))   in ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u');

CITY
----------
Alondoni
eroma
Iud apesta

SQL>
```

Line #10 extracts the first character, while line #11 does that for the last one.

(I didn't feel like searching for valid city names so I *fabricated* them).

Comment: Alexandria, Ankara, Oslo, Anchorage, Ottowa, Osaka, Addis Abbaba ;) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_national_capitals, https://www.sporcle.com/games/viator_mundi/largest-cities-starting-and-ending-in-a-vowel/results

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
with 
cte1 as (select distinct UPPER(city) as cityUC from station),
cte2 as (select SUBSTR(cityUC,1,1) as first, SUBSTR(cityUC,-1) as last, cityUC from cte1),
cte3 as (select cityUC from cte2 where first in('A','E','I','O','U') and last in('('A','E','I','O','U')
select distinct(s.city) 
from cte3 c, 
join STATION s
on c.cityUC = s.UPPER(city);
```

If you don't care about cities being all uppercase you can just select them from cte3

Using Gordon's hint we also have, the cleaner:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(city) FROM STATION
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (city, '^[aeiouAEIOU].*[aeiouAEIOU]$');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a substring function to get the first and last characters, and require them to be `IN ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')` set.

Or you can use LIKE with two combined sets, to reduce to eleven conditions:

```
(name LIKE 'a%' OR name LIKE 'e%' OR name LIKE '%i' ...)
AND
(name LIKE '%a' OR name LIKE '%e' OR ...)
```

Depending on indexes and database engine, either could be faster. Or it could be best to use the more practical regular expression match (in my experience this can be slow even when indexes are used. I never really investigated why. On the other hand, the ease of use of the regex could offset the performance impact, even if you did experience one).